# Is it possible to check set parameters in google ads?

Tags: ads, google-ad-manager, personalization, gdprconsentform

We have an implementation with google ads on our website.

On a desire to be cookie politics compliant we are limiting ads personalisation choices.
Our CMP gives us the opportunity to block that automatically and propose us to use a code similar to this.

```
  googletag.pubads().setPrivacySettings({
     nonPersonalizedAds: false,
  });
```

and

```
  googletag.pubads().setPrivacySettings({
     nonPersonalizedAds: true,
  });
```

Is there any way to check that that parameter has been correctly set? I have tried many ways to access that object after setting this param but couldn't find anything proper until now in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference), there is no way to retrieve the setPrivacy config from the API. It might be hidden somewhere in the googletag object, but I was not able to find it.

Saddly, even the [official console](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/publisher-console) does not seem to get this parameter shown...

Until Google Ad Manager allows us to get this param value dynamically, there is a work around to check your ad requests' privacy settings status :

1. go to your page and open the development tool
2. go to tab network and filter all entries with "doubleclick npa=1"

If there are results, it means your ad requests included the nonPersonalizedAds: 1 parameter. If no results, then nonPersonalizedAds was set to 0.

Comment: Thank you that worked fine! We first had to set nonPersonalizedAds: true, insted of 1 to make this work.